# Зачем нужен пункт в настройках про актуальные вопросы сети, если они у нас и так не выводятся?

Tags: поддержка, настройки-профиля, актуальные-вопросы-сети

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У нас этого меню вообще нет. К примеру, на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так зачем этот пункт?

Comment: Чтобы очередной раз напомнить, что от пользователя здесь мало что зависит?..)

Comment: А может лучше выводить их, а не пункт убирать?

Comment: @Qwertiy может и лучше (:

Comment: @Qwertiy кстати, у испанцев эта менюшка есть https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions